# 403 Forbidden Error when calling AWS API from Netlify App

Tags: java, vue.js, cors, aws-api-gateway, netlify

I have a VueJS front end hosted on Netlify and my Java Spring Boot backend is running in a container on an EC2 instance. I created an HTTP API through AWS to route traffic from the frontend to the backend since the EC2 public IPv4 was not an HTTPS address. I have configured CORS on the API and setup a proxy in Vue that should allow the Vue frontend to talk to the API. However, I keep getting 403 errors.

I've tried all sorts of configurations and proxies and can't find the winning combo. This is what I have right now:

```
CORS configuration in AWS:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin
https://(site-name).netlify.app

Access-Control-Allow-Headers
content-type, authorization

Access-Control-Allow-Methods
POST
OPTIONS
DELETE
GET

Access-Control-Expose-Headers
date
x-api-id

Access-Control-Max-Age
300 Seconds

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
YES
```

Vue Config

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy:  'https://<AWS API ID>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
  }
}
```

Example fetch form front end

```
const apiURL = 'https://<AWS API ID>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

const response = await fetch(`${apiURL}/api/transaction?id=${transactionID}`, {
method: 'GET',
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
```

Comment: 403 is a server response (server tells you you're not authorized to do something), that's not CORS (browser decides your site isn't allowed to access some foreign resource). Are there any credentials that might get lost in all those proxying steps?

Comment: I don't know and I'm not sure how to find out.. the API works fine in Postman and even in the browser but not from app. That's why I thought it might be CORS?

Comment: If there's something wrong with CORS you should see something in the browser dev console while the web request should go though with 2xx. Would check in browser dev tools where this goes wrong, it possible that a vue proxy turns a cors error from the browser into a 403 internally

Comment: There's also a good chance it's something like https://jwstanly.com/blog/article/How+to+solve+SAM+403+Errors+on+CORS+Preflight/ - cors preflight requests result in 403 errors because they are sent without credentials

Comment: Why are you including a `Content-Type` header to your `GET` request? `GET` requests are not meant to have a body.